# Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1146

Tags: error, database, grid

I’m working on a new site, using a fresh install of 2.7.2. Everything’s been going swimmingly (sort of), until now I went to edit some custom fields. When I click on a field name to do an edit, I get the following:

> A Database Error Occurred Error Number: 1146 Table
>   'my_database_name.exp_grid_columns' doesn't exist
>
> SELECT * FROM (`exp_grid_columns`) WHERE `field_id` IN (11) AND
>   `content_type` = 'channel' ORDER BY `col_order` Filename:
>   models/grid_model.php
>
> Line Number: 631

Using phpmyadmin, I see that there is in fact no “exp_grid_columns” table in the database. So what does that mean? Should I just create a table with that name? Not actually sure what’s involved with that….

I saw a bunch of 1146 error codes relating to the Comment module in the EE Forums, but this doesn’t seem to have anything to do with that (I even tried installing the Comment module).

I’m not really a MySQL person, so I’m not sure where to go from here. Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Is the Grid fieldtype enabled?

Answer (score 1):

You should have that table in your database. Here's what it should look like.

[image removed by user]

You may need to (re)install the Grid fieldtype under Add-ons > Fiedtypes. If it's already installed, uninstall it and install it again.

**Update**

In your database, check the `exp_fieldtypes` table. If you have a row for `grid`, delete it. Delete the new `exp_grid_columns` table you tried to manually add.

Comment: Thanks for this tip! I didn't in fact have the exp_grid_columns table in my database. However, EE shows that the grid fieldtype is installed. I went to uninstall, but it wouldn't uninstall because it couldn't find the table! So I tried adding the table (I'm not really a MySQL person...), but then when I tried uninstalling Grid fieldtype I got: `A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146
Table 'ninemain_abdbase.exp_content_types' doesn't exist
DELETE FROM `exp_content_types` WHERE `name` = 'grid'
Filename: models/grid_model.php
Line Number: 129`   any ideas on where to go from here?

Comment: See updated answer. After that, try reinstalling Grid.

Comment: Thanks for following up! Following your directions did allow me to try to reinstall Grid, but then I got this new error message: `
A Database Error Occurred
Error Number: 1146
Table 'ninemain_abdbase.exp_content_types' doesn't exist
INSERT INTO `exp_content_types` (`name`) VALUES ('grid')
Filename: models/grid_model.php
Line Number: 102 `   It looks like my database is missing some things! Do you think it's best to just start with a clean install? This site doesn't have a lot of data in it yet because it's new...

Comment: Ugh, yeah, re-download EE in case you have a corrupted file and start all over. :)

Comment: Yes, thanks for the original idea. I'm not sure where things went wrong; whether in an update to 2.7 or by not updating all my modules first.... hard to say. But I think the least time-consuming idea is just to start over. Thanks for your interest and help!